# Let $C\subset E$ be a convex subspace and $a\in E\setminus C$. The point in $C$ closest to $a$ is unique.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $E$ be a vector space with a norm $|\cdot|$ induced by an inner product, $C\subset E$ a convex set, and $a\in E\setminus C$. Show that if there are $x_0,x_1 \in C$ such that $|a-x_0|\leq |a-x|$ and $|a-x_1|\leq|a-x|$ for every $x\in C$, then $x_0 = x_1$.

Picturing a ball, the only point with such property is the one closest to $a$, which is unique, so the question makes sense. However, I haven't been able to use convexity of $C$ to finish the proof.

I found similar questions in the context of real analysis, but couldn't abstract the logic.

Comment: You have to imagine it if you wish to solve it: If you work in $\mathbb{R}^n$  for example and you assume by contradiction there exists two closest points then you have a triangle (whose vertices are the original point and these two points) this triangle has two edges of the same length. Now using "high school" geometric you can find 
a closer point (the middle of these two points). Note that you have to rely on the fact that you work on an inner product space, it will not be true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint: If $x_0 \ne x_1$ are both at distance $d,$ then one of the points interior to the segment joining $x_0$ to $x_1$ should be at distance less than $d.$

Comment: This, plus @Yanko's proof by contradiction suggestion, plus the above answer reminding me of the parallelogram identity led to a straightforward solution that makes sense. Your answer was the inception, though. Thanks.

Comment: If $C$ was not convex, then the midpoint between $x_0$ and $x_1$ could be outside $C$ so there would be no contradiction. Is that where we used it?

Comment: @big-lion Yes, convexity is what guarantees all points on the segment between $x_0,x_1$ are in $C.$

Answer (score 2):

The geometric proof others have suggested would also be the way I'd recommend proceeding. However there does exists a more analysis based proof. Let $d = \inf_{x \in C} \lvert a - x \rvert$ and $(x_i) \subset C$ be any sequence such that $\lvert a - x_i \rvert \to d$ as $i \to \infty$. We aim to prove $(x_i)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since the norm arises from an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, we know the norm satisfies the parallelogram identity:
$$ \lvert v + w \rvert^2 + \lvert v - w \rvert^2 = 2\lvert v \rvert^2 + 2\lvert w \rvert^2 $$
Plugging in $v = a - x_i$ and $w = a - x_j$ and rearranging gives that
$$ \lvert x_i - x_j \rvert^2 = 2\lvert a - x_i \rvert^2 + 2 \lvert a - x_j \rvert^2 - 4 \lvert a - \tfrac{1}{2}(x_i + x_j) \rvert^2$$
Since $C$ is convex we know $\frac{1}{2}(x_i + x_j) \in C$ therefore $\lvert a - \frac{1}{2}(x_i + x_j) \rvert \geq d$. Moreover since $\lvert a - x_i \rvert \to d$ as $i \to \infty$ we can find $N$ such that for all $i \geq N$ we have $\lvert a - x_i \rvert^2 < d^2 + \epsilon$. Then for all $i, j \geq N$ we have
$$ \lvert x_i - x_j \rvert^2 < 2(d^2 + \epsilon) + 2(d^2 + \epsilon) - 4d^2 = 4\epsilon $$
Therefore $(x_i)$ is Cauchy.

Now suppose that $\lvert a - x \rvert = d$ is achieved for two points in $C$, say $v_0$ and $v_1$. Then we can take $(x_i)$ to be the alternating sequence $v_0, v_1, v_0, v_1, \ldots$ and the above shows this sequence is Cauchy. So in fact $v_0 = v_1$.

This proof has some value because if we further assume $C$ to be complete (in particular $C$ is complete if $E$ is a Hilbert space and $C$ is closed), we know any Cauchy sequence has a limit. Therefore taking any $(x_i) \subset C$ such that $\lvert a - x_i \rvert \to d$, we know $x_i \to x$ for some $x \in C$ as $i \to \infty$. Moroever by continuity of the norm $\lvert a - x \rvert = d$. Therefore if $C$ is complete and convex, we can always achieve the minimum distance from $C$ to any point.

Comment: This is a really good, general answer, but it didn't work the intuition, which helped me get to the answer. It's good to have it around, though, thanks. edit: I mean, this is just what I did, but it wasn't so general